# Switching between word documents interop

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interop, appium

I have created a number of unit tests. At the beginning of each test I create an instance of word. For a certain unit test I need to open a second instance of word however it opens behind the first instance and I'm not sure why it is doing this. I have tried many things such as making it the active application and setting the as the focus but I've had no luck. I'm using interop to try and do this and Appium to try and run the unit tests. How would I make the second instance of Word come to the front?

My code is as follows

```
[TestClass]
public class Word
{

    private const string wordId = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.exe";
    private const string AppDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
    private static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> wordSession;

    private static string wordTitleTemp = @"N:\Testing\V8\TestMaster\V8.6\Testing\V8.6.0.11 Testing\wordTitleTemp.docx";

    [TestInitialize]

    public void SetUp()
    {

        var appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", wordId);

        var initialSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(AppDriverUrl), appCapabilities);

        var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("app", "Root");
        wordSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(AppDriverUrl), capabilities);
        wordSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void wordTitle()
    {

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        var wordApplication = new word.Application();
        var myDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(wordTitleTemp);
        wordSession.CloseApp();
        wordApplication.Visible = true;
        var paragraphs = myDocument.Paragraphs;
        word.Paragraph paragraph = paragraphs.First;
        word.Range paragraphRange = paragraph.Range;
        word.Sentences sentences = paragraphRange.Sentences;
        word.Range firstSentence = sentences.First;
        firstSentence.Select();
        wordApplication.Activate();
        wordApplication.WindowState = word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
        word.Window window = myDocument.ActiveWindow;
        window.SetFocus();
        window.Activate();
        myDocument.ActiveWindow.SetFocus();
    //wordSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        //wordSession.FindElementByName("Close").Click();//Close out of opened Word as it gets in the way


        wordSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wordSession.FindElementByName("Create").Click();

        wordSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wordSession.FindElementByName("Heading 1").Click();



    }
```